# ROC AUC score for AutoEncoder and IsolationForest

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I am a new in Machine Learning area & I am (trying to) implementing anomaly detection algorithms, one algorithm is Autoencoder implemented with help of keras from tensorflow library and the second one is IsolationForest implemented with help of sklearn library and I want to compare these algorithms with help of roc_auc_score ( [function from Python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score)), but I am not sure if I am doing it correct.

In documentation of roc_auc_score function I can see, that for input it should be like:

**sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average=’macro’, sample_weight=None, max_fpr=None**

**y_true :**
True binary labels or binary label indicators.

**y_score :**
Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers). For binary y_true, y_score is supposed to be the score of the class with greater label.

**For AE I am computing roc_auc_score like this:**

```
model.fit(...) # model from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential
pred = model.predict(x_test) # predict function from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#predict
metric = np.mean(np.power(x_test - pred, 2), axis=1) #MSE
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, metric) # where y_test is true binary labels 0/1
```

**For IsolationForest I am computing roc_auc_score like this:**

```
model.fit(...) # model from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html
metric = -(model.score_samples(x_test)) # https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.score_samples
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, metric) #where y_test is true binary labels 0/1
```

I am just curious if returned roc_auc_score from both implementations of AE and IsolationForest are comparable (I mean, if I am computing them in the correct way)? Especially in AE model, where I am putting MSE into the roc_auc_score (if not, what should be the input as y_score to this function?)

Answer (score 3):

Comparing AE and IsolationForest in the context of anomaly dection using `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` based on scores coming from AE MSE loss and IF `decision_function()` respectively is okay. Varying range of the y_score when switching classifier isn't an issue, since this range is taken into account for each classifier when computing the AUC.

To understand that AUC isn't range dependent, remember that you travel along the decision function values to obtain the ROC points. Rescaling the decision function values will only change the decision function thresholds accordingly, defining similar points of the ROC since the new thresholds will lead each to the same TPR and FPR as they did before the rescaling.

Couldn't find a convincing code line in `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score`'s [implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L246), but you can easily observe this comparison in published code associated with a research paper. For example, in the [Deep One-Class Classification](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/ruff18a.html) paper's code (I'm not an author, I know the paper's code because I'm reproducing their results), AE MSE loss and IF `decision_function()` are the `roc_auc_score` inputs (whose outputs the paper is comparing):

### AE roc_auc_score computation

Found in [this script](https://github.com/lukasruff/Deep-SVDD-PyTorch/blob/master/src/optim/ae_trainer.py) on github.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

(...)

scores = torch.sum((outputs - inputs) ** 2, dim=tuple(range(1, outputs.dim())))

(...)

auc = roc_auc_score(labels, scores)
```

### IsolationForest roc_auc_score computation

Found in [this script](https://github.com/lukasruff/Deep-SVDD/blob/master/src/isoForest.py) on github.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

(...)

scores = (-1.0) * self.isoForest.decision_function(X.astype(np.float32))  # compute anomaly score
y_pred = (self.isoForest.predict(X.astype(np.float32)) == -1) * 1  # get prediction

(...)

auc = roc_auc_score(y, scores.flatten())
```

**Note:** The two scripts come from two different repositories but are actually the source of a single paper's results. The authors only chose to create an extra repository for their PyTorch implementation of an AD method requiring a neural network.